# Why isn't the value of default-only variable added to an outbound URL as part of the query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Why isn't the value of *default-only variable* `myVar` added to *outbound URL* as part of a *query string*:

```
    routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}",
        new { myVar = 1 });
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
         @Html.ActionLink("click me", "CustomVariable", "Home", 
                  new { myVar = 1, newMyVar = 1000 }, null);
```

From the above *routing system* generates:

```
       <a href="/Home/CustomVariable?newMyVar=1000">click me</a>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your routing rule you are stating that if the default value is not provided, then use this value.

So there is really no need to provide the value when it is the same as the default value, because it will simply use the default value.

Comment: "In your routing rule you are stating that if the default value is not provided, then use this value." No, this is a default-only variable, which means that it never occurs in URL pattern